# aiohttp.web.Application и var_dump for Python: RecursionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

Кто-нибудь пробовал применить var_dump (https://github.com/sha256/python-var-dump) к экземпляру aiohttp.web.Application?

```
from var_dump import var_dump
from aiohttp import web

app = web.Application()
var_dump(app)
```

У меня печатает многа-многа строк, сразу ясно, что намного больше, чем нужно, видно что что-то не так. И так печатает, пока не появится:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Где собака порылась?

Comment: Возможно, в Application есть ссылка на тип, у которого есть ссылка на этот же тип и это вызвало зацикливание

Comment: если `L = L[0] = [1]; var_dump(L)`  также к бесконечной рекурсии ведёт и это поведение явно не документировано (что var_dump() не поддерживает [self-referential] рекурсивные объекты, которые сами на себя ссылаются), то это *баг в `var_dump()`*